# Installing shower niche on outside wall

Tags: bathroom, siding

I am thinking about installing niche on outside wall. One of my concerns I have is that if siding needs to be changed, during installation of the new one, nails can go through the plywood and penetrate the niche. Is this a legitimate concern, or are nails will not go that deep?

Update: The wall is made from 2x4's and I am located in NJ. I am thinking about using Reflectix insulation in the cavity of 2x4's where niche will go.

Update 2: Is it a good idea to add another set of 2x4's to existing wall to make niche stand out 4" from the wall? Not grow the whole wall, but only part where niche will go. Here is the drawing of what I mean.

[image: niche]

Comment: More information is needed.

Comment: Is the wall a 2X4 wall or 2X6? What are your winters like?

Comment: I updated OP with needed information

Comment: "Is it a good idea to add another set of 2x4's to existing wall to make niche stand out 4" from the wall?" a bump out on the _outside_? Sure, if that's what you want, but it will be a royal pain to handle your exterior finishes - sheathing, house wrap, siding, trim, paint, etc. Hope I misunderstood you!

Comment: @FreeMan, I meant on the inside, but then I measured and and with bathroom being 48"x48", I am afraid I it will in the way of movement around the shower. Having said that, should I be concerned with nails going through the plywood hitting the niche?

Comment: A drawing of your two proposed ideas would help people visualize where this is to go and what you're looking at. Don't have to be high quality, just a sketch would do, so long as we can make out what's going on and it has some dimensions.

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment - should I  be concerned with nails going through the plywood and hitting niche if I were to install niche in existing 2x4 cavity?

Comment: @FreeMan Added drawing of proposed structure

Comment: What is the point of building framing to make a niche stand out from a wall?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of a niche?  Why not, then, just install shelves on the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarity from your drawing, I would *definitely* add the framing to the inside for your niche.

If you don't, you'll end up with a basically uninsulated hole in your shower. If you're in a cold climate (and Jersey can get chilly, especially this week), that will make your bathroom frigid, especially when you're taking a shower.

Siding nails *could* be a concern as well at some random point in the distant future, but the primary issue is the lack of insulation which you'll feel every cold day in the fall/winter/spring.

Comment: Is mold growth concern with little insulation? And I am talking about about 2" compressed insulation behind the niche.

Comment: Sounds like fodder for a whole new question, @positron. Question scope creep is not looked kindly upon 'round here. :) Also, questions & answers in comments aren't searchable.

Comment: noted thanks. In my defense I did say "One of my concerns" :)